# How to enable scrolling and disable paging in a dynamic gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a dynamic gridview, want vertical scrolling functionality and disable paging altogether

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the gridview inside a div and set the height of the div. Like

```
  <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;height:200px">
   --your Gridview
  </div>
```

It worked for me ,where the paging is off for the Gridview.

Answer (score 0):

in gridview PageIndexChanging you must change PageSize to big number size

```
gridview.PageSize = 100
```

or more than 100

for vertical scrolling use java

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Refresh" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```html
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ScrollableGridViewPlugin_ASP.NetAJAXmin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
            ScrollHeight: 300,
            IsInUpdatePanel: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: based on the code above, got the scrollbar. However, its throwing an unhandled exception on javascript (javascript run time error)